# Symfony2 bundle assets directory name

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible for to tell Symfony2 to install bundle assets in the directory `bundle/frontend/` instead of `bundles/<vendor>frontend/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will always use the bundle's name.

However, if VendorFrontendBundle is an application specific bundle (which I assume), I would recommend not to use a vendor. Vendors are only usefull when you want to share your bundle in multiple projects.
Furtermore, I would also suggest to just place the application specific assets in `/web/assets/frontend` directly. It makes no sense to put them in a bundle.